# Account owner JWT claims

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

I've an application where user's authorizations are managed by JWT tokens.

On this application, for each account, I've:

- an `account owner`
- account `members` that use the same account of the owner but with less rights

So, for example, a `member` can edits some elements created by the `account owner` but not all.

I could use `roles` or `scope` to achieve this, but I prefer to store the identifier of the `account owner` on the token to not introducing a SPOF. Because if I don't have the `account owner`, I need to retrieve it from another service (or store it to all other services).

I will store the `members` identifier to the `sub` JWT claims but, following the [RFCs](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml), I didn't find the appropriate claims to store the `account owner` identifier.
Is there any convention to store this kind of `account owner` identifier?